# Popen.stdin.write is not working with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

`Popen.stdin.write` is not working with Python3

I am initiating a telnet connection to a remote device and start sending the commands.
Below is a simple example which makes a telnet connection to the remote device and starts sending device specific commands [i.e "vr" , "KP on"]

---

```
import subprocess

telnet_client = subprocess.Popen(
    ["telnet", "192.168.1.120", "4002"],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True)

#Get Version
telnet_client.stdin.write('vr\n')
telnet_client.stdin.flush()

#Power on the device
telnet_client.stdin.write('kp on\n')
telnet_client.stdin.flush()

#Factory default
telnet_client.stdin.write('fd\n')
telnet_client.stdin.flush
```

Every `stdin.write()` is not throwing any exception or any error, just returns number of bytes written. But actually the message is not sent.

## Ubuntu machine1:

I observed after installing Python3 in the machine, the above implementation stopped working with Python2.7

## Ubuntu machine2:

In another Ubuntu machine after installing Python3, the above implementation works with Python2.7 but it doesn't work with Python3.

So common thing, in any direction `Popen.stdin.write` doesn't work with Python3. I believe some packages are screwing the system.

Comment: Without knowing more about the behavior of `cec-client`, it's impossible to say. For example, if that program is trying to write to its sdout or stderr before it processes the commands you're writing on stdin, those writes would be blocking with this code. Which is to say -- there are plenty of explanations for this behavior *vastly* more plausible than `Popen.stdin.write` being broken (and somehow nobody noticing).

Comment: You flush "after" write, not before.

Comment: Can you build a [mcve] that doesn't depend on a program other folks are unlikely to have available (and even more unlikely to have hardware necessary to test)? If you can demonstrate an issue with `subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)` (note, *not* redirecting stdout or stderr), that's something folks-who-aren't-you will have a much easier time reproducing.

Comment: ...by contrast, if you want to further track down your `cec-client` issue, consider replacing it with `['strace', '-s', '2048', '-o', 'cec-client.strace', '-f', '--', 'cec-client', '-d', '8']`, and then reading `cec-client.strace` to see which specific syscalls are blocking. (Or use `sysdig` or a similar tool to do syscall-level tracing less invasively).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your response. I have edited my example which makes a simple telnet connection to remote device. I mean through telnet also stdin.write() didn't worked with Python3. Can you please provide details on how to track sysdig logs to see  who is blocking this.

Comment: `sysdig 'proc.name=cec-client'` and posting the results somewhere I can get to them (f/e a [gist](https://gist.github.com)) would be a starting place; I'm happy to help with the interpretation.

Comment: BTW, if you want a raw socket, I'd use Python's `socket` module, or at least netcat or socat. `telnet` is a client for a [much more complicated protocol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet), and whether it tries to write a connection message to stderr before talking to the network (and potentially doesn't get around to the network connectivity if given a stderr that blocks on write attempts) is up to your OS vendor (though the sysdig trace will make it clear if that's what's happening).

Comment: *Thus far*, though, there's nothing to dispell the impression that your problem is caused by `stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE`; if there's content the `telnet` client is trying to write to those descriptors *before* it reads from its stdin, the writes aren't guaranteed to complete, so the reads aren't guaranteed to happen either. Details depend on exactly how the FIFOs are configured for buffering, which is why this makes sense as behavior that varies between versions.

Answer (score 3):

This is all set.

Actually server is receiving the data after calling stdin.flush

```
telnet_client.stdin.write('vr\n')
telnet_client.stdin.flush()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. `process.stdin.write()` works in Python 2.7, but not in Python 3. Though I couldn't debug what the issue was, I was able to achieve the functionality with `process.communicate()`. [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate). This is the recommended way of communicating with a process. Also, the string we pass as input to this method needs to end with a `'\n'`.

Comment: This works because `communicate()` reads from stdout and stderr, so writes to them don't block. Redirecting stdout and stderr to *any other non-blocking sink* will work just as well.

Comment: (A `'\n'` on the end of stdin isn't universally required by the `subprocess` module itself -- but on UNIX, lines of text are newline-*terminated*, not newline-*delimited*, so well-behaved UNIX applications may not consider something a valid line of textual input if there isn't a newline after it).

Comment: process.communicate() works if we are executing a single command i.e Execute "ls -l" simply runs and exits the process and returns the results.The situation I am running is something like run the process and starts interacting to that without exiting the process. Example: When you try to make an ssh connection, it tries to expects user inputs (yes/no) to authenticate. Do let me know, Is any one able to achieve this kind of scenario using python3

Answer (score 0):

To make stdin work I have used the following 2 lines to communicate in python3

```
p.stdin.write(bytes(string+'\n', 'utf-8'))
p.stdin.flush()
```

and from the child process, I am doing `stdout.flush` to communicate back to the parent.